# Is there a way to simultaneously test two or more assertion in pytest test cases

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest

I have a  test case written in selenium python such as the following

> This is a test case written in pytest

```
def test_calculations():
   a = 5
   b = 6
   assert a+b == 10,"addition error"
   assert a-b == -1,"subtraction error"
```

now i want a way such that when i run this test both of these assertions should be performed regard less of the previous assertion being failed and then provide specific result for specific assertion

Comment: `assert (a+b, a-b) == (10, 1)`

Comment: If these assertions can fail independently, it's hard to understand why you don't want two tests?

Comment: Yeah... I can do two different tests, one for addition, one for subtraction and the result would be perfect 
but I wanted to carry out these two comparison using one single test case,
kind of like using one test for calculating multiple operations rather then using multiple individual test cases for individual operation

Comment: Note that metatoaster’s hint perfectly demonstrates that this is not a pytest issue. Anything which can be evaluated as a bool can be asserted. You just need to define how you want to set up your tests. That said, the more complex your tests the harder they will be to maintain and the more likely it will be that your tests themselves might have an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put those two tests in a tuple like in [metatoaster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73781399/is-there-a-way-to-simultaneously-test-two-or-more-assertion-in-pytest-test-cases#comment130282775_73781399). But  I will first clarify:

1. It should be clear you can't "test everything simultaneously".
2. Tests are meant to stop at the first failure. Consider what would happen if PyTest didn't behave like that an instead always proceeded - any "real" failure  would be followed by more failures which have nothing to do with the code being tested. Example:

   ```py
   obj = MyClass()  # returns None
   assert obj is not None  # PyTest should fail here
                           # but imagine if it behaves how you wanted
   assert obj.do_action() == 10  # AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'do_action'
   ```

   - In your case for Selenium, if there was a `button = driver.get_element...` and the `assert button is not None` failed, your next step for `button.click()` would still fail. So it's better for Pytest to stop after a failure.
3. Things which you want to test independently should be individual tests or **Iterations** of a test.

If you want two checks to run independently of each other, then put them as **individual iterations** with [`parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html#different-options-for-test-ids). Each iteration runs independently of the previous, so each check can run as its own test.

```py
import operator
import pytest

testdata = [
    (operator.add, 10),
    (operator.sub, -1),
]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("operation,expected", testdata)
def test_each_operation(operation, expected):
    a = 5  # these should actually be in the test data
    b = 6
    assert operation(a, b) == expected
```

Result, note the "1 failed, 1 passed" below:

```
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
FAILED pytest_iterations.py::test_each_operation[add-10] - assert 11 == 10
========================= 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.04s =========================
```

Better layout:

```py
import operator
import pytest

testdata = [
    (5, 6, operator.add, 10),    # fail
    (5, 6, operator.sub, -1),    # pass
    (5, 10, operator.mul, 100),  # fail
    (5, 10, operator.mul, 50),   # pass
]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("a,b,operation,expected", testdata)
def test_each_operation(a, b, operation, expected):
    assert operation(a, b) == expected
```

Result: 2 failed, 2 passed:

```
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
FAILED pytest_iterations.py::test_each_operation[5-6-add-10] - assert 11 == 10
FAILED pytest_iterations.py::test_each_operation[5-10-mul-100] - assert 50 ==...
========================= 2 failed, 2 passed in 0.04s =========================
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap every assert in a try except block:

```
def test_calculations():
    a = 5
    b = 6
    try:
        assert a + b == 10, 'addition error'
    except AssertionError:
        print('Addition error')
    try:    
        assert a - b == -1, 'subtraction error'
    except AssertionError:
        print('subtraction error')
```